# Time efficient clean up of large areas and small but important areas

Tags: bathroom, tile, cleaning, kitchen-counters

I have:

1. a large area/wall with tiles (bathroom) and
2. a smaller area with tiles on top and around the kitchen/food counter.

The grout etc is fine, I was wondering what is an efficient way for general sanitary cleanup of both areas that wouldn't require huge amount of time (e.g. wet sponge for case 1) or lots of water to rince (for case 2).

What do you recommend?

Answer (score 2):

1. For larger tile walls, if you don't need to scrub the grout, I recommend something like [a car wash mop](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B089KBG31C).  It's soft enough it won't hurt the tile, wide enough you can clean quickly, and the microfiber can get in between the grout and the tile.  If you don't have an extendable showerhead for rinsing, you can rinse off the mop pretty well and use it to get the soap off the walls.
2. For the smaller areas, a wet paper towel or washcloth will do the trick for everyday cleaning.  If you run into more difficult stains, be sure to use an appropriate cleaner for your type of tile.  Most can be cleaned with a baking soda and vinegar mix, but not all.  [Here is a guide from Zameen](https://www.zameen.com/blog/clean-kitchen-backsplash-tiles.html) for different types of tiles and how to clean them